# Get Values from child nodes from XML | Python

Tags: python, elementtree

I have the following XML.

I am using ElementTree library to scrape the values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
 <url>    
  <loc> Test1</loc>
  </url>
 <url>
  <loc>Test 2</loc>
 </url>
 <url>
  <loc>Test 3</loc>
 </url>
</urlset>
```

I need to get the values out of 'loc tag'.

Desired Output:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

Tried Code:

```
tree = ET.parse('sitemap.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for atype in root.findall('url'):
 rank = atype.find('loc').text
print (rank)
```

Any suggestions on where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has a default namespace (`http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`) so you either have to address all your tags as:

```
tree = ET.parse('sitemap.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for atype in root.findall('{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}url'):
    rank = atype.find('{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc').text
    print(rank)
```

Or to define a namespace map:

```
nsmap = {"ns": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"}

tree = ET.parse('sitemap.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for atype in root.findall('ns:url', nsmap):
    rank = atype.find('ns:loc', nsmap).text
    print(rank)
```

Comment: Yeah. I nearby forgot about it. Thanks for noticing it out. Yeah. I addressed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import etree


tree = etree.parse('sitemap.xml')
    for element in tree.iter('*'):
        if element.text.find('Test') != -1:
            print element.text
```

Probably isn't the most beautiful solution, but it works :)

Comment: Are we searching for the text which is inside the <loc> tag ?

Comment: It will check all elements in sitemap.xml, so 
     URLSET element
     URL element (<url> )
     LOC element (<loc>) -> text found -> text got printed.
     URL element (<url>)
     LOC element -> text found -> text got printed.
etc.